# Calling a method via an array within the same model in which the members are defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to keep all my model functionality in one place. I'd like to be able to call its methods within it:

**JS**

```
/**
 * This app prints "OK" a number of times, according to which button is pressed
 */
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.okModel = {
    oks: [],
    addOne: function(){
      this.oks.push(["OK"]);
    },
    addTwo: function(){
      this.addOK();
      this.addOK();
    },
    buttons: [
      {name:"addOK", action: this.addOne}, // THIS is where the issue is I think
      {name:"add2OKs", action: this.addTwo}
    ]
  };
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <!-- print the object holding all the "OK"s -->
  oks: {{okModel.oks}} 

  <!-- show the buttons -->
  <button ng-repeat="item in okModel.buttons" ng-click="item.action()">
    {{item.name}}
  </button>

  <!-- print the "OK"s -->
  <div ng-repeat="ok in okModel.oks">
    {{ok[0]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not getting an error, but it's not working either. No "OK"s are being added to the model. It seems like the issue may be with the `okModel.buttons` action property.

Here's a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/mDk43yEKSQB37QSmiKJn?p=preview

**TL;DR**: I realize that the issue is probably with `this` in `buttons`, what should I use instead?

---

Bonus question: I'm new to angular and realize I may be using models incorrectly. If you know of a better way to do models, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked, the "angular" way to do this is to have a service provide the model, rather than defining it in your controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('modelService', function() {
  var okModel = {
    oks: [],
  }
  okModel.addOne = function() {
    okModel.oks.push(["OK"]);
  };
  okModel.addTwo = function() {
    okModel.addOne();
    okModel.addOne();
  };
  okModel.buttons = [{
      name: "addOK",
      action: okModel.addOne
    },
    {
      name: "add2OKs",
      action: okModel.addTwo
    }
  ];

  return okModel;
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'modelService', function MyCtrl($scope, modelService) {
  $scope.okModel = modelService;
}]);
```

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/mRmI1QkNHHIOLfInub4y?p=preview).

Comment: Perfect! Quick questions: why are both `'modelService'` and `ModelService()` here? Why is that necessary? What's the difference?

Comment: Actually, it looks like I conflated two different ways of defining a service.  (There are many.  Let me fix it)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `this`, try using `$scope.okModel`. The actual object where `this` refers to is not always what you expect. It depends on how the function is invoked.

EDIT:

You can pull the definition of the functions out of the `okModel` like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyCtrl($scope) {

    var addOne = function() {
      $scope.okModel.oks.push(["OK"]);
    };

    var addTwo = function() {
      addOne();
      addOne();
    };

    $scope.okModel = {
      oks: [],
      addOne: addOne,
      addTwo: addTwo,
      buttons: [{
        name: "addOK",
        action: addOne
      }, {
        name: "add2OKs",
        action: addTwo
      }]
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: `Cannot read property of undefined` I have a plunker if you want to try it out: https://plnkr.co/edit/mDk43yEKSQB37QSmiKJn?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, I had them outside at one point, just wondering if it's possible to do it all within the same object.

Answer (score 0):

@reeverd answer seems to be correct. Here is a little more clean up.

```
  $scope.okModel = {
    oks: [],
    addOne: function(){
      oks.push(["OK"]); // you don't have to push an array with the OK text. You can just push in the OK text itself.
    },
    addMulti: function(cnt){
      for (var ii = 0; cnt < ii; ii++) {
          // this.addOK(); this may also be your issue addOK function is not defined.
          $scope.addOne(); // calls the addOne and pushes OK into the oks array.
       }
    },
    buttons: [
      {name:"addOK", action: $scope.addOne}, // THIS is where the issue is I think
      {name:"add2OKs", action: $scope.addMulti(2)}
    ]
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this` inside the `{name:"addOK", action: this.addOne}` in the array is the object itseld, and not the object wrapping the array. In this case you could do something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
   .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyCtrl($scope) {

// Here you declare the functions which are going to modify
// $scope.okModel.oks
var addOne = function() {
        if ($scope.okModel) {
            $scope.okModel.oks.push("OK");
        }
    },
    addTwo = function() {
        addOne();
        addOne();
    };

    $scope.okModel = {
      oks: [],
      addOne: addOne, // Here you assign okModel.addOne to the functions declared above
      addTwo: addTwo, // Same here
      buttons: [{
          name: "addOK",
          action: addOne // Same here
      }, {
          name: "add2OKs",
          action: addTwo // Same here
      }]
    };
  }]);
```

First you declare the functions which will modify `$scope.okModel.oks` array and then you use that same funcions both in your model methods and in your model buttons.

**EDIT:** Here you have a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/sKUxjzUyVsoYp3S7zjTb?p=preview